# How to show a notification to the user if a textfield is left blank

Tags: java, input, textfield

How can you show a `JOptionPane` notification to the user when a textfield is left blank?

I am new to Java

I made a button to submit a name, and if the user submits a blank, it gets a blank also. Is there a certain method from the textfield to determine whether the textfield is blank or not, so I can give alert that the textfield is blank from `JOptionPane`?

Comment: Before executing the button code, you could check the textfield contents (using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText-- for example) and display a warning message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the button's ActionListener:

```
if (textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textField, "Beware: you left the text field blank");
}
else {
    proceedAsUsual();
}
```

Comment: You're a saint, may god bless you